# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 when writing query results to csv

Tags: python, utf-8, python-unicode

I am reading a query as text from a google sheet which is being passed as "str1" below. Here is my code:

```
# get query string from google sheets
# establish database connection
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute((str1))
results1 = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for row in results1:
    ws.append(row)
```

At which point I get the error as shown in the title:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 790, in append
    cell = Cell(self, row=row_idx, col_idx=col_idx, value=content)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.value = value
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 294, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 191, in _bind_value
    value = self.check_string(value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 150, in check_string
    value = unicode(value, self.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 48: invalid start byte
```

The data is regarding author/article information (we are a publisher). It contains content id, site code, byline, author, link to facebook ad, and pull date/time

Here is an example of a row of data which held an error:

```
(1693279, 'CPD', 'Morgan Dietrich', "20 Intuitive People Share Their 'Something Doesn\x92t Feel Right' Story That Turned Out To Be True", 'business.facebook.com/550634765042035/posts/…;, datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 29, 20, 49, 24))
```

I have read a lot of questions regarding this error but cannot figure out a solution. The results of the query (results1) - which runs successfully - are a tuple like this:

```
( (query result ro1/col1, query result ro1/col2, query result ro1/col3), 
  (query result ro2/col1, query result ro2/col2, query result ro2/col3), ... etc... )
```

I have tried .encode/.decode but they don't seem to work on a tuple. I've tried filtering for the bad characters but that didn't work.

How in the world do I resolve this issue? These utf8 related errors have caused me so much annoyance in the past and as much as I read it all still seems fairly confusing.

The row that fails is

```
(1693279,
 'CPD',
 'Morgan Dietrich',
 "20 Intuitive People Share Their 'Something Doesn\x92t Feel Right' Story That Turned Out To Be True",
 'https://business.facebook.com/550634765042035/posts/1223000787805426',
 datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 29, 20, 49, 24))
```

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* of the exception, not just the last line. That way we can see where Python got into trouble, and how it got there. Just the exception is pretty useless to us.

Comment: We also probably need to know what type of data is contained in the rows. Where did this data come from? What kind of text is contained in it?

Comment: sorry, i'm new to this. I've included the information you requested, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: The error is caused by you passing binary data to the `ws.append()` call. *At least one* of the columns in a row is not decodable as UTF-8. Perhaps you could catch the exception and print that row to share with us? `try:` (indent), `ws.append(row)` then unindent, `except UnicodeDecodeError:`, indent, `print(row)` and `raise` to exit at that first error.

Comment: awesome, I didn't know how to do that previously. Here is where it went wrong:

Comment: (1693279, 'CPD', 'Morgan Dietrich', "20 Intuitive People Share Their 'Something Doesn\x92t Feel Right' Story That Turned Out To Be True", 'https://business.facebook.com/550634765042035/posts/1223000787805426', datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 29, 20, 49, 24))

Comment: Do you need the traceback again? Looks the same other than it being in line 3 rather than 2 File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>

Comment: Please edit your question with that last comment data. No need to add the traceback again, I just wanted to prevent you from running through all data.

Comment: Now, do you know what codec as used for that data? What database is this? Some databases can produce decoded Unicode data for the right columns if correctly configured.

Comment: At first glance I'd say this is Windows Codepage 1252 data, where 0x92 is the [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+2019) codepoint, which would make sense in the context.

Comment: I'm not super sure on those questions, I will have to look more into it tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: For example, if this was MySQL or Oracle, we can figure out the correct configuration to get you the data *as Unicode strings*, so you don't have to manually decode here.

Comment: it is mysql, yes

Comment: Can you share the table schema and your connection statement?

Comment: Also see [Python & MySql: Unicode and Encoding](//stackoverflow.com/q/8365660)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bytestring data with non-ASCII and non-UTF8 data in them. You'll either have to configure your database to return Unicode strings instead for that 4th column, or manually decode.

The 0x92 byte is the [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+2019) codepoint if you decode the data as Windows Codepage 1252 (or a number of other windows codepages in the same range, but 1252 is the most likely for otherwise English text), so you could just try that:

```
for row in results1:
    row = list(row)  # convert to list for easier mutation
    row[3] = row[3].decode('cp1252')
    ws.append(row)
```

Comment: thank you so much! that worked. i will try to format my questions more appropriately next time as well.